# Wattmeter Required for Transfomer Characterization?

Tags: transformer, ac

I have to characterize and test a small 6VA 230VAC Transformer. 
Seems like I will do

1) Winding Resistance Test - DC Test

2) Open Circuit Test

3) Short Circuit Test

I do not have a wattmeter, but I do have two multimeters. 
Wherever a wattage is required, I can just measure the Amps and multiply it with the Voltage, right?

Example Procedure: http://iitkgp.vlab.co.in/?sub=39&brch=124&sim=924&cnt=2

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not have a wattmeter, but I do have two multimeters. Wherever a
>   wattage is required, I can just measure the Amps and multiply it with
>   the Voltage, right?

No, that doesn't work in AC circuits when the impedances are reactive/complex.

There is a thing called "power factor" - this relates actual power to the RMS values of current and voltage. If you have a pure inductor supplied with an AC voltage and AC current will flow. This does not mean that a power is produced by the inductor of \$V_{RMS}\cdot I_{RMS}\$.

Because, for a pure reactive component current and voltage are displaced by 90 degrees, the theoretical power is zero.

Comment: Hi Andy. So if I had a wattmeter, the reading on the wattmeter would not have been the same as VxI for an AC source of say 230V? I have to compare two similar transformers (same model and specs) to determine the better supplier, If i do just use V*I - I would at the end of my tests come to results that are consistently INCORRECT, but I might still be able to spot the better supplier. Can I do this or will I just be wasting my time?

Comment: I'd add a bridge rectifier to the transformer under test, then smooth the output with a capacitor and put full load on it - now you can measure output power in terms of DC into the load. I'd be interested how much the transformer gets warm so maybe a thermocouple on the core to measure temperature. Testing unit A and unit B side by side might also be a good idea.

Comment: Thank you, Just had a discussion with one of my colleagues and he suggests the same.